# How to clone multiple children with React.cloneElement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to clone React elements like this, to pass the parent props to them (the props are not assigned in this example):

```
React.createElement('div',
    {
        style: this.props.style
    },
    React.cloneElement(this.props.children, null)
)
```

This however returns following error:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a
>   string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined.

If there is only one child or if I pass React.cloneElement(this.props.children[0], null), there is no error and the desired element is rendered.

How can I clone multiple elements?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`children` props is an opaque structure, it can be `undefined`, an array, or a single react element. You should use the [`React.Children` utilities](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children) to map over the `children` structure :

```
const style = this.props.style
React.createElement('div',
    { style },
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child => React.cloneElement(child, { style })))
)
```

Comment: Smallest of notes - missing closing `))` at the end there

Comment: **Note:** If `children` is a single element or `Fragment`, it will not be traversed.

Comment: @GreeKatrina If it's a single element (not a Fragment) of course it will be traversed.

Comment: @asliwinski The docs says no. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap

Comment: @GreeKatrina you must be reading different docs then, definitely not what you're linking to:
"Note

If children is a Fragment it will be treated as a single child and not traversed."

Nothing about single element not being traversed.

Comment: It does actually traverse a single Fragment too. Check this code:

```
const TestComponent = ({children}) => {
  return <div>
    {React.Children.map(children, (child => {
      debugger
    }))}
  </div>
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <TestComponent>
          <>
          </>
        </TestComponent>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @asliwinski I took it as saying that a Fragment is equal to a single child, and therefore will not be traversed, because single children are not traversed. But yes, I [tested it as well](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-surf-03yr6), and Fragments are traversed. *insert eye roll*

Comment: Fragments and single children are not traversed. The function is invoked directly on them. If children is an array THEN the array is traversed and the function is invoked on each child.