# How to clone React.Node type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code, that does not compile:

```
import React, {PropsWithChildren} from "react";
import useScrollTrigger from "@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger";


export default function ElevationScroll({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {

    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0
    });

    return React.cloneElement(children, {
        elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
    });
```

The error message:

```
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.  TS2769

    10 |     });
    11 | 
  > 12 |     return React.cloneElement(children, {
       |                               ^
    13 |         elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
    14 |     });
    15 | }
```

Looking at the type definition of `ReactNode`:

```
type ReactChild = ReactElement | ReactText;
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

`ReactNode` can be also `ReactElement`.
However why `React.cloneElement` does not accept `children`?

**Update**

How I am going to use `ElevationScroll`:

```
<ElevationScroll>
    <AppBar color="default" elevation={0} classes={{colorDefault: classes.appBar}}>
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <img alt="logo" src={logo} className={classes.logo}/>
            </Toolbar>
        </Container>
    </AppBar>
</ElevationScroll>
```

As you can see, it contents only one child.

I have changed the implementation of `ElevationScroll`:

```
export default function ElevationScroll({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {

    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0
    });


    return React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), {
        elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
    });
}
```

The compiler still complains:

```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | ReactPortal | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.  TS2769

    11 | 
    12 | 
  > 13 |     return React.cloneElement(React.Children.only(children), {
       |                               ^
    14 |         elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
    15 |     });
    16 | }
```

I have also tried:

```
export default function ElevationScroll({children}: PropsWithChildren<{}>) {

    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        disableHysteresis: true,
        threshold: 0
    });


    return React.Children
        .map(children, (ele) => React.cloneElement(ele, {
            elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
        }));
}
```

compiler complains:

```
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, any> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.  TS2769

    12 | 
    13 |     return React.Children
  > 14 |         .map(children, (ele) => React.cloneElement(ele, {
       |                                                    ^
    15 |             elevation: trigger ? 3 : 0,
    16 |         }));
    17 | }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone multiple children with React.cloneElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38011702/how-to-clone-multiple-children-with-react-cloneelement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide `ReactNode` (`children` type) as `ReactElement`. The issue is `ReactNode` also includes fragments, ordinary text and other primitive values. You have to cast it beforehand (not so good) or (better) check your carefully children

If you only want to support single child - use `Children.only`.
If you want to clone multiple elements - use `Children.map`.

If you want to support fragments you should also check if given element is a fragment and then do whatever you want - ignore it, use its' children instead.

Read more about `Children` utility here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Comment: It seems Typescript definitions are a bit odd for `Children.only` as this function is ignoring primitives. I've created a sandbox with an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bird-zf2z9). As you can see I redefined `children` as an `ReactElement`. It's okay as long as you are sure this component should only allow one Reactish child to be provided. Second way is to use `isValidElement` to be 100% sure or just cast value returned from `Children.only`.

Comment: What do you mean with `primitives`?